# Typo3 Session lost in MS-Edge when opening a new window

Tags: session, microsoft-edge, typo3-8.x

I'm experiencing a strange problem with the Edge-Browser.

I'm using an ajax-call to login a user. As long as the user is in the same window, the session vars seem to be persistent.
But as soon as I open a new window (target="_blank") the session vars seem to be lost and the user isn't logged in anymore. The session vars are gone in the opening window as well.

I'm using this to set and get the session vars:

```
$sessionData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', self::$prefixKey . $key);

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', self::$prefixKey . $key, $sessionData);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
```

It's happening in all versions of Edge - interestingly, for once it doesn't happen in IE.

Any ideas?

[Edit for clarification]: The new window is on the same domain as the opening one. No subdomains, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Edge browser are you using? Please refer to the following steps to make sure you are not disabled cookies in Edge browser:

1. Open Edge browser, click on the More actions button in the top right
   corner and select **Settings**.
2. Click **View Advanced Settings**. You’ll need to scroll down to the
   bottom of the page.
3. Press the dropdown arrow under the Cookies field.
4. Select **Don't block cookies**.

If still not working, try to [reset the Edge browser setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).